# Regex expression for -- OR - OR \s

Tags: java, regex, split

I'm trying to create a regex expression for a split function that will split on a single dash (-) or a double dash (--) or a space character (\s). I'm trying "[-\\s]" but that returns an extra empty string when it hits the double dash.

"12-34 56--7 89".split("[-\\s]"); returns

```
12 
34
56

7
89
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `"--?|\\s"`.

Personally i'd see if any number of dashes or whitespace would work as a separator, and in that case instead use `"[-\\s]+"`.

Note also that `\\s` is not the space character. It means any whitespace character. If you want just the space character, use `"--?| "`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use "(?:--|-|\\s)" for your regexp

Comment: it says that's not valid

Comment: Sorry, stackoverflow showed only one '\'. Now it's right (tested).

Comment: The `(?:)` non-capturing group is redundant as it's not part of a bigger pattern.

Answer (score 0):

This code does you want.  Note it uses | for or.  It also uses parens to show the double dashes go together.

```
String test = "a-b--c d";

String[] values = test.split("(--)|-|\\s");

for(String s: values) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Comment: Ah I forgot the parens... Thanks!

Comment: The extra parentheses do nothing. It's just `"--|-|\\s"`, or simpler, `"--?|\\s"`. Personally i'd probably use `"[-\\s]+"` to split on any number of dashes or whitespace.

Comment: The extra parens make it clearer that the -- go together and it isn't a dash followed by a dash or whitespace.  My goal when writing a regex is for it to be apparent what it does even if someone doesn't know the rules of precedence of regex patterns.  And [-\\s]+ isn't equivalent to what Tsvi asked for.  if the pattern could be broader, sure that's a good way of doing it.  I suspected it can't given the phrasing of the question.

Comment: The extra parentheses are entirely redundant. Parentheses are used to create a capturing group, which isn't needed here. It's the `|` that says the dashes go together.

Comment: I didn't say they weren't redundant.  I said I think they make it clearer for some readers.

Comment: They're dead code that makes the regexp more complex for no reason, and your answer is misleading. Now anyone reading it without reading my comments will think the parentheses are required.

Answer (score -1):

You could try something like :

```
"[-\\ ]+"
```

Example :

```
String str = "12-34  - 56--7 89";
String[] arraySplit = str.split("[-\\ ]+");
for (String s : arraySplit){
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

The result :

```
12
34
56
7
89
```